# Studying the action of $GL(V)$ on the vector space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

The statement I am trying to prove is the following.

> Let $k$ a field and $V$ a $k$-vector space of finite dimension. Let
>   $\mathscr{B}$ be the set of ordered $k$-bases of $V$. The natural
>   action of $GL(V)$ on $V$ induces an action on $\mathscr{B}$.
>
> (a) Is this action transitive

**Answer**: I think I have managed to show that it is (unless I am terribly wrong).

> (b) Describe the stabilizer of each element of $\mathscr{B}$.

**Answer**: I am finding the stabiliser to be trivial, but I think I might be making some mistake which I cannot identify. Maybe I am correct though.

> (c) Show that this action induces a bijection of sets between $GL(V)$
>   and $\mathscr{B}$. Did you make any choice to construct such a
>   bijection?

I don't have anything for the last one. If anyone would suggest a bijection, I could check myself that it is actually one.

Thank you all very much in advance for your time. Any help will be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: You are doing well for a and b. For c, do you know the orbit stablizer theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got (a) and (b), and (c) is asking you to put the two together.

Any time you have a group $G$ acting on a set $X$, if you pick a point $x \in X$, you get a bijection between the $G$-orbit of $x$ (often written as $G \cdot x$) and the set of left cosets of the stabilizer of $x$ (typically written as $G / G_x$).

Pick any ordered basis $B = \{v_1, \dots, v_n\} \in \mathscr{B}$.  What does (a) tell you about the $GL(V)$-orbit of $B$?  What does (b) tell you about the stabilizer of $B$?

Comment: Thank you very much! It is all clear now!